# Parameter of Brauer algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, classical-invariant-theory

Let $O(V)$= the set of orthogonal transformation from the vector space $V$ to $V$ where $\dim V=n$. We know that the centralizer algebra of $O(V)$ on the tensor space $V^{\otimes{f}}$ is Brauer algebra $B_{f}(\delta) $ where $\delta$ is a parameter. Could you please explain the connection between $\delta $ and $\dim V=n $

Comment: They are equal.

Comment: Wales conjecture says for integer values of $\delta $  $B_f (\delta ) $  is not semi-simple. Then Centralizer of $O(V)$ is not semi-simple ?

Comment: In Wale's conjecture that  $B_f(\delta)$ is semisimple unless $\delta\in\mathbb{Z}$, the dimension $n$ is understood and $\delta$ is any real number. Wale's conjecture was proved by Wenzl at https://sites.math.washington.edu/~billey/classes/Hopf.algebra/bulletins/wenzl.1988.pdf.

Comment: But is not $\delta =n$ ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's answered in the first paragraph of the Wikipedia page on Brauer algebras.

Comment: To clarify further: normally, given $f$ one takes $n$ sufficiently large so that we get the full Brauer algebra and not a proper quotient of it. The notation $B_f(\delta)$ assumes that $n$ is sufficiently large, viz., $n\geq 2f$. Then $B_f(\delta)$ is independent of $n$ and depends on the parameter $\delta$. The discriminant $\Delta_f(\delta)$ of $B_f(\delta)$ is a polynomial in $\delta$. $B_f(\delta)$ is semisimple if and only if $\Delta_f(\delta)\neq 0$. If $B_f(\delta)$ and $B_f(\delta')$ are both semisimple, then they are isomorphic.